# Constraints aren't working for different iPad sizes

Tags: ios, ipad, autolayout

I'm making an app with a piano keyboard and so far I have the white and black keys looking great for every iPhone device and the iPad pro 9.7 inch. However, on the other iPad's my top constraint on the black keys isn't working. My black keys are getting pushed above the white keys:

[image: iPad 12.9]

I know I can add specific constraints just for iPad but the thing is that my constants would have to be different for each iPad because each iPad has different heights.

This is what it should look like on the other iPads
[image: iPad 9.7]

Currently the top constraint has a constant of 134:
[image]

[image]

**Edit:**

The white keys and black keys have the same constraint to the top. Which is even more weird for me. Here's a picture of the top constraint for the white keys.
[image]

[image]

**Edit:**

Here is a picture of the warnings that are showing for my black keys when I switch to iPad device on Xcode.
[image]

When I delete the b.width = 0.048913xwidth constraint, the rest of the warnings are gone but the black keys are still positioned where they are..

Comment: Can you constrain the tops of your black keys to be equal to the tops of the white keys?

Comment: See, that's what makes me more confused. The top constraints of the white keys and black keys are the same. Both have a constant of 134. I'll upload another image.

Comment: Then you probably have a constraint conflict and the system is making your white keys farther from the edge than the black keys.  If you constrain the white keys to just be equal to the tops of the white keys they should snap into place.

Comment: What are the other constraints on the white keys?

Comment: The constraints on the white keys are for them to have equal width and height. They all have equal bottom constraints and a top constraints. However one key has an aspect ratio constraint which causes the rest of the white keys, I'm guessing, to conform to the height and width that results from the aspect ratio.

Comment: I just realized that when I switch to iPad device in Xcode that I get warnings. I'll upload a picture of them.

Comment: Yeah.  The aspect ratio will set the height of your white keys and then something has to give.  You could lower the priority of the bottom constraint and then the white keys would move up.

Comment: Or get rid of the aspect ratio constraint and let the white keys stretch.

Comment: I got rid of the aspect ratio but nothing changed. All the keys are contained inside UIbuttons and have background images one thing to notice is that the background image isn't stretching to fill the entire UIButton of the white key when in iPad device. If you look in the picture you will see that.

Comment: Did you try leaving the aspect ratio constraints alone and lowering the priority of the bottom constraints for the white keys?

Comment: So I went back to a previous version of this project because for some reason the version I was working on got corrupted. The version I'm working on now is exactly the same except the white keys don't have an aspect ratio but it still looks the same. I tried lowering the priority and it still didn't work. I'm running out of options :/

Comment: I found a fix..So I set the control of the image to stretch vertically. This pretty much fixed it except now my title is out of place and moving the title insets around is different for every device so I think I'll just use labels but the grand problem is now fixed

Comment: You could set the top of the black images equal to the top of the white images. That way they are always equal.